# JQuery - Test window has been resizes over a threshold

Tags: javascript, jquery

hope you can help

My current project requires me to recall a set of functions on window resize so that I can keep the responsive nature correct. However the code I am using is rather twitchy as it calls the functions even if the window is resized by 1px.

I am relatively new to jQuery but learning more and more every day, but this is something I'm struggling to find a way to do.

In an ideal world I would like to call the functions when the window has been resized over a breaking point at anytime, for example:

say the breaking point is 500px, the initial load size is 400px the user resizes to 600px, so over the threshold so call the functions again. 
It would also need to work in reverse... so window (or load) size 600px, breaking point 500px, resize to 400px call functions.

Here's the code I'm currently:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

var resizing = !1;
 $(window).resize(function(a) {
   !1 !== resizing && clearTimeout(resizing);
   resizing = setTimeout(doResize, 200);
});

function doResize() {
  call_these_functions();       
}
```

Cheers for the help guys

---

Thanks for the reply Zze

I am using something similar to what you've put, but I have it based within the start of my functions to filter what each thing does based on the window size. My problem is that these are getting called far too often and causing issues / twitchy behaviour.

For example I'm having issues on a tablet I'm testing on, when you scroll down, the scrollbar that appears  on the right seems to trigger the window resize... causing functions to be called again that automatically accordion up or .hide() elements to their initial loaded state.

So my thinking is if I can test it's actually broken a set threshold rather than just what size the window is then it will be far more reliable.

Comment: Please explain us what you have tried so far, and what kind of problem you are experiencing. Stackoverflow is here to get help with specific problems or to ask for guidance. We cant write the code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i've found a solution that's going to do what i need with a little work (fingers crossed as i'm currently working on it), from http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/

Thanks for the help Zze

Answer (score 0):

There are some really handy jQuery functions available and it looks like you are very close to cracking this yourself. Hope this helps though.

```
$(window).resize(ResizeCode); // called on window resize
$(document).ready(function(e) { ResizeCode(); }); // called once document is ready to resize content immediatly

function ResizeCode()
{
   if ($(window).width() < 500){    
       //insertCode
   }
   else if($(window).width() >= 500){
       //insertCode
   }
}
```

***Update***
If we are looking to 'restrict' the call time of this function, then you could add an interval which updates a bool every time it ticks, and then check this bool in the previous code:

```
var ready = true;
setInterval(function(){ready = true;}, 3000);

function ResizeCode()
{
    if (ready)
    {
        // run code
        ready = false;
    }
}
```

But i would suggest storing the width and height of the window in a var and then comparing the current window with the var when the window is resized, that way you can tell if the window has actually been resized over 'x' amount or if it is that weird bug you've found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zze, I've added a little bit more information about my problem. If you could have another look I'd really appreciate it.